MongoDB The best model between relational collections
for example i have 3 collection:
user:
db.users.insert({ _id: 1, username: 'mark' });
db.users.insert({ _id: 2, username: 'leon' });
db.users.insert({ _id: 3, username: 'leontin'});

providers:
db.providers.insert({ _id: 1, name: 'prov1' });
db.providers.insert({ _id: 2, name: 'prov2' });
db.providers.insert({ _id: 3, name: 'prov3' });
db.providers.insert({ _id: 39, name: 'prov39' });

data:
db.data.insert({
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfa'),
      user: 1,
      provider: 1,
      message: '94451 Laos Sweden Iran',
    });
db.data.insert({
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfb'),
      user: 2,
      provider: 3,
      message: 'message  22222',
    });
db.data.insert({
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfc'),
      user: 3,
      provider: 39,
      message: 'message  3333',
    });

P.S.  i have more 2 related collection with 'date' but i write the example only with 2 related (normally are 4 collections)
i search  '2 likes'  ..   over  3.200.000  rows in data,  20.000 users, 10000 providers
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "providers",
      "localField": "provider",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "provider_info"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: {
                $first: "$user_info.username"
              },
              regex: "^leo",
              options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: {
                $first: "$provider_info.name"
              },
              regex: "^prov3",
              options: "i"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

example query:   https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Nw_B4iV-CW
the result are about 15+ seconds    and i need over 100.000.000 in data collections (users and providers are ok)
i have index in  data.user, data.provider,  users.username, providers.name
how to improve this relations ?    thinking that the 4 collections will constantly change the data (users.username,  providers,name, ..., ...)
Regards, amic

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yl09SFADqTv does this improve speed

@cmgchess   no, is slower

@cmgchess i test again and again, and the difference is slower

also, this solutions  // lookup + unwind + match user_info    from:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/hPG6dzkvj7w,    the same, difference is slower, and is very high for this number of rows

As before: Note that Case-insensitive indexes typically do not improve performance for  $regex  queries. If you don't need case-insensitive matches, then remove the options: i part.

Read up on Data Modeling. If you need to frequently access the User name & Provider name, then add it to your data collection instead of always looking it up.

You might want to start your aggregation from either users or providers collection and apply the $match to minimize the intermediate result as soon as possible.

@aneroid about removing  options: i , i don't see big change
...
about adding user, provider , and 2 more, to  data collection, i don't know, because, the fields can change the values, and i need to change the entire data collection, each time, ..

This seems like you are accessing  a lot of data frequently between the collections using the $lookup operations.
It is good to note that, $lookup is an expensive operations, hence, MongoDB being the flexible data model allows you to store data using different design patterns and relationships.
If restructuring the database design is an option, you might want to change the data collection and store the users and providers in the same collection.
having said that, this is just an example where you can think of restructuring the database design.
The complete performance of the query would however would also be dependent on the Indexes being created and many other parameters.
My recommendation here would be to go through the MongoDB Data Modelling Path for further understanding.
Please reach out for any further questions.
Regards
